# cannot access tor ownership

Tags: permissions, sudo, tor

I've tried the recommended options to gain ownership of tor browser and am still not successful. This is the script I got:

```
sudo chown $USER-Rv~/.tor-browser
chown: missing operand after `m-Rv~/.tor-browser'
Try `chown --help' for more information.
m@m:~$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /usr/bin/tor-browser <BR>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
m@m:~$ sudo chown-R USERNAME /usr/bin/tor-browser
[sudo] password for m: 
sudo: chown-R: command not found
```

I have no idea where I went wrong with this. Tor browser has downloaded successfully, but it can't be activated.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are commands that are correctly used.

- You are missing spaces in this one:

  ```
  sudo chown -Rv $USER ~/.tor-browser
  ```
- Here USERNAME is not a valid word. Plus what is the < BR >!?

  ```
  sudo chown -R $USER /usr/bin/tor-browser <BR>
  ```
- Again missing a space but USERNAME is not a correct word. :

  ```
  sudo chown -R $USER /usr/bin/tor-browser
  ```

These 3 should be the valid method for each of the commands. Options (probably mandatory) go in front of the $USER (that is substituted for your current user).